# I Cant Put Thread.sleep() in my Class extends Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

i Use Socket To communicate between android and wifi its return me OutOfMemory Error When i Trying to disconnect 3 seconds after Sending Data

i have an interface to handle data:

```java
public interface SocketConnections {

    public void onSocketConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected, Socket socket);

    public void onMessageRecieved(String Message);

    public void onMessageSent();
}
```

SocketClass

```java
public class connectSocket implements Runnable {

    public Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private InputStream in;
    private SocketConnections connections;
    private static final String TAG = "connectSocket";

    public connectSocket(SocketConnections connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() {
        disconnect();
        try {
            try {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            socket = new Socket(wsConfig.HOST_ADDRESS, wsConfig.PORT_NUMBER);
                            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                                connections.onSocketConnectionChanged(true, socket);
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
                                while (socket.isConnected()) {
                                    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                    in = socket.getInputStream();
                                    String S;

                                    if (in != null) {
                                        while (true) {
                                            byte[] content = new byte[1024];
                                            try {
                                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                                int bytesRead = in.read(content);
                                                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                byte[] x = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, 0, bytesRead);
                                                Log.i(TAG, "run: " + x.length);
                                                S = Util.fromByteArrayToHexString(x);
                                                connections.onMessageRecieved(S);
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            connections.onSocketConnectionChanged(false, socket);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public void sendData(final byte[] S) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    out.write(S);
                    out.flush();
                    connections.onMessageSent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
                connections.onSocketConnectionChanged(false, socket);
//                Toast.makeText(G.context, "سیستم به سرور متصل نیست.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to add 3 seconds delay after sending data and Disconnect
like this

```java
 public void sendData(final byte[] S) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    out.write(S);
                    out.flush();
                    connections.onMessageSent();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
```

its return me out of memory error and force close what should i do?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` (a) has nothing do do with `OutOfMemoryError`, but (b) has no place in networking code. `Socket.isConnected()` is not a valid test for a `while` condition, and cannot possibly be false at either of the points you are testing it. `if (in != null)` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. Never ignore an exception. There are so many things wrong with this code it is too broad to answer.

Comment: @user207421 my code is works good its send data and receive and no error until i put delay in send data method

Comment: Why did you nest two `try {...} catch(Exception ignored) {}` blocks?

Comment: @SolomonSlow that is my bad one of them is useless

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok so i found my problem and solved it. i'm not sure but i think when i'm trying to sleep thread inside other thread its some how its going to stop itself before start or i don't know whats happens there but when i put sleep in other method and call that in my first thread its works fine. if some one know about it tell us

Comment: In other words you still haven't the faintest idea. 'Sleep thread inside other thread' is meaningless, as is 'stop itself before start'.